# How to pull relationship data into another relationship field?

Tags: relationships, related-entries

I'm building a site using relationships and have run into something that's got me stumped. I suspect it's something simple but can't for the life of me see what it is.

I have the following channels and fields:

**Channel: training_course_dates**
**Field:** training_course (single relationship to training_course_overview channel)

**Channel: training_course_overview**
**Field:** course_testimonial (single relationship to testimonials channel)

**Channel: testimonials**
**Field:** testimonials_quote

What I'm trying to do is to show an entry from the {training_course_dates} channel, pulling in the course overview information, including the related testimonial but this is where I'm getting stuck.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="training_course_dates" 
    dynamic="yes" 
    url_title="{segment_4}"
    status="open" 
    limit="1"
    cache="yes" 
    refresh="1440"
}
    <div class="feature_box">
        <p>
            {training_course}   
                {training_course:course_testimonial}
                    {training_course:course_testimonial:testimonials_quote}
                {/training_course:course_testimonial}
            {/training_course}  
        </p>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And here's what's getting output:

{training_course:course_testimonial} 
{training_course:course_testimonial:testimonials_quote}
{/training_course:course_testimonial}

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: I suspect the problem may be related to my use of opening and closing tags, which I believe are only required for multiple relationships. Sadly when I try to use a single tag {training_course:course_testimonial:testimonials_quote} I just get a blank white screen? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First thing would be to change the dynamic="yes" to dynamic="no" since you are selecting the entry by segment.

did you try something like 
    {training_course:entry_ids} 
           {training_course}
                {training_course:course_testimonial:entry_ids}
            {/training_course}
to see if you are getting entry ids?

Answer (score 0):

I've now managed to sort this one using an embed. Not the optimum solution for performance I know, but without being able to get the double layer of relationships to work this solution now does the job.

I used an embed on the main template and pass through the training course URL title to use in the embedded template like so:

```
{embed="/training/testimonial_embed" 
     training_course="{training_course}{training_course:url_title}{/training_course}"
}
```

I then use that information on the embedded template to display the required data like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="training_course_overview" 
    status="open" 
    limit="1"
    cache="yes" 
    refresh="1440"
    url_title="{embed:training_course}"
}
    <div class="feature_box">
        <p class="testimonial_quote">“{course_testimonial:testimonials_quote}”</p>
        <p class="testimonial_name">{course_testimonial:title}</p>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Hope that helps anyone with a similar challenge.

Tom